# OpenSSL X509_Sign "invalid digital signature"

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to use the OpenSSL libcrypto / libeay library to create a simple cetificate / key pair. The code is based on the mkcert.c demo included with the OpenSSL source code.

The demo itself works fine and creates a valid self-signed certificate. Now I'm trying to create a certificate signed by a parent CA certificate. I've modified the demo (see below) to sign using a different certificate / key. The program compiles and runs, however when inspecting the newly created certificate in Windows the certificate is reported as invalid - "This certificate has an invalid digital signature." (see image)

[image: Invalid digital signature]

This does not happen when signing using the OpenSSL command line app. I'm attaching a link to the code (apparently it's a little too long for Stack Overflow), please try to see what I'm doing wrong.

[mkcert-mod.c](http://pastebin.com/7z8f4rKD)

Answer (score 0):

OK apparently it also happens via the command line.. this is weird by itself but is more relevant to Superuser now.